# NullPointerException even if object is not null

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

I'm developing an application for which i'm decoding the JSON response using java. Following is the code snippet where i'm getting occasional NullPointerException

```
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
URL url=new URL("http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?q="+
URLEncoder.encode(dish,"UTF-       8")+"&_app_id=APP_ID8&_app_key=APP_KEY");
HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
Object json=parser.parse(br);
JSONObject obj=(JSONObject)json;
if(obj!=null)
 count=(long)obj.get("totalMatchCount"); <--- Exception at this point
```

this statement is running in a loop and giving NullPointerException at random iterations.

Comment: The NPE probably happens inside the `get()` method.

Comment: show `stacktrace` and you probably get insight where exception happens

Comment: it gives me that exception is at this line. If there was an exception in get then it must be there in stack trace.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at YummlyAuthenticate.getRecepieCount(YummlyAuthenticate.java:115)
 at YummlyAuthenticate.parseXML(YummlyAuthenticate.java:54)
 at YummlyAuthenticate.main(YummlyAuthenticate.java:130)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you that obj.get("totalMatchCount") is returning null, and blowing up in the cast to a long.

Something like

```
Object countObj;
if(obj!=null) 
   countObj = obj.get("totalMatchCount");
if (countObj != null)
 count=(long)countObj
```

Now why, whether and if it should be null, is something else.

Comment: do you have any idea what something else can be?

Comment: Have to look at the code that does getTotalMatchcount. Looks like teh json object your url is returning doesn't have a property called that.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject#get` returns *null if the object does not contain a key with this name.* (javadoc). so most likely the Json response does not contain a key `totalMatchCount`.

Check for spelling, check if the response *should* contain that key (and if it actually has a value) and check if the actual response really has that key (maybe you receive some error response or something else that's unexpected).

Use a debugger, catch the NPE and inspect the json object carefully.